# Ngixg reverse proxy - real ip

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having trouble getting the client's ip sent to the backend server behind an nginx reverse proxy,
I've tried a little of each with the proxy_set but unfortunately without luck

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;

 # SSL config
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain/domain.net.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain/domain.net.key;

 server_name domain.net www.domain.net;

 set $upstream 10.0.1.10;

 location / {
 proxy_pass_header Authorization;
 proxy_pass https://$upstream;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Connection "";
 proxy_buffering off;
 client_max_body_size 0;
 proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot `proxy_set_header Forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded;`